# Python: Selenium submit

Tags: python, selenium, submit

Does someone know the difference between those 2 keywords from Selenium:

```
element.submit()

element.submit
```

I've some forms working with the first one, and others working with the second.

For example,

```
self.webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/input').submit
```

return a result while

```
self.webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/input').submit()
```

returns another.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question with some working example of `element.submit`?

Comment: What do you mean by "`self.webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/input').submit` return a result" ? What result? Everything might *"return a result"*... Can you put more meaning into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the current *API Docs* of [**`selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) the method [**`submit()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.submit) is defined as follows :

```
submit()
    Submits a form.
```

As per the source code, `submit()` looks for the `ancestor-or-self` as `form`, creates an event and dispatches. In case of failure `Command.SUBMIT_ELEMENT` is executed.

Source Code :

```
def submit(self):
    """Submits a form."""
    if self._w3c:
        form = self.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor-or-self::form")
        self._parent.execute_script(
            "var e = arguments[0].ownerDocument.createEvent('Event');"
            "e.initEvent('submit', true, true);"
            "if (arguments[0].dispatchEvent(e)) { arguments[0].submit() }", form)
    else:
        self._execute(Command.SUBMIT_ELEMENT)
```

So, it's apparent that **`submit()`** is the full proof approach to follow though in some cases **`submit`** may also cater to your needs. But following the *Best Practices* `submit` must be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

In python functions and methods are first-class objects. We can call them by using some parentheses (brackets) on the end.

But sometimes we don't want to call them, we just want to pass a reference to the callable(function) itself, In those cases, we can simply avoid using parentheses.

Therefore, whenever you are using the function, then we must use parentheses. And whenever we need to pass this method as argument to some other method, then we can omit parentheses.