# How can I submit an HTML form using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was testing *177.6.167.168* in my Python script which uses Selenium.

I tried:

```
password_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

and

```
login_form.submit()
```

where `password_input` is the password input in the login form, and `login_form` is the only form in the page.

Is there a universal solution for this problem?
I understand that the first approach won't fix this as if I try as a human to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the password field, nothing will happen...

Comment: This looks like a mega duplicate. What is the canonical question?

Answer (score 2):

As per the Selenium-Python API documentation of [webelement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement), the method [`submit()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.submit) is described as:

```
submit()
    Submits a form.
```

And is defined as:

```
def submit(self):
    """Submits a form."""
    form = self.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor-or-self::form")
    self._parent.execute_script(
        "var e = arguments[0].ownerDocument.createEvent('Event');"
        "e.initEvent('submit', true, true);"
        "if (arguments[0].dispatchEvent(e)) { arguments[0].submit() }", form)
```

---

### This use case

The HTML would have helped us to construct a more canonical answer. However, once you supply the password, you can also simulate submitting the form in either of the following ways:

- Using *`Keys.RETURN`*:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  password_input.send_keys("Daniel" + Keys.RETURN)
  ```
- Using *`Keys.ENTER`*:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  password_input.send_keys("Daniel" + Keys.ENTER)
  ```
- Using *username* element and *`submit()`*:

  ```
  username_input.submit()
  ```
- Using *password* element and *`submit()`*:

  ```
  password_input.submit()
  ```
- Using *form* element and *`submit()`*:

  ```
  form_element.submit()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Python: Selenium submit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50489634/7429447)

Comment: Hi, form.submit doesn't work here: http://177.6.167.168/login.cgi

Comment: Why would you avoid the _**Login**_ button click there?

Comment: However, the following steps works perfect at my end: 1. _`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='usernames']"))).send_keys("Daniel")`_ 2. _`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='passwords']"))).send_keys("Daniel")`_ 3. _`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Login']"))).submit()`_

Comment: I'm looking for some universal solution, how can I check if key.return worked or not and then (if not) try form.submit and if not try to click button?